# Transaction not starting Spring + Hibernate + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a problem with transactions in Spring not starting and thus changes made to database are not saved. Configuration is as follows:

web.xml (there is no dispatcherServlet, there is FacesServlet)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Relevant configuration from applicationContext.xml is like this:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="pl.web.beans,pl.csci.dao" />

<bean id="sessionFactoryCsci" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:csci_database.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplateCsci" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactoryCsci" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateDaoSupportCsci" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport" abstract="true">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateCsci" />
</bean>

<bean id="csciPermSystemDAO" class="pl.csci.dao.CsciPermSystemDAO" parent="hibernateDaoSupportCsci">
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactoryCsci" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Finally the class responsible for saving entities:

```
pl.csci.dao
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CsciPermSystemDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements ICsciPermSystemDAO {
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Integer addPermission(Permissions Permission) throws DaoException {
    try {
       Integer permissionId = (Integer) getHibernateTemplate().save(Permission);
        LOGGER.info("Is transaction active?:" + DebugUtils.transactionActive() );
        return permissionId;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // exception handling
    }
}
```

Code from above snippet (DebugUtils.transactionActive()) returns false. This method uses TransactionSynchronizationManager class to determine wheter transaction is active or not.

When debugging Hibernate, I can see logs from inserts, but those inserts acutally never appear in a database:

2014-01-30 15:13:15 DEBUG [hibernate.SQL] - insert into csci_perm.permissions (BRANCH, GROUP_ID, PERSON_ID, READ_PERM, SYSTEM_ID, WRITE_PERM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my configuration?

Finally, here is hibernate configuration:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/csci_perm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">100</property>
    <!-- seconds -->
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout - You can disable this once you have it working -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
    <mapping class="pl.csci.model.Permissions"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: how do you define your TransactionManager?

Comment: I have edited first post

Answer (score 0):

It could be that database does not support transaction.

Check this  [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

> MySQL Server (version 3.23-max and all versions 4.0 and above) supports transactions with the InnoDB and BDB transactional storage engines.

Comment: I run command 'show table status;' on MySQL database and it shows that InnoDB engine is used. Also when i run 'show engines' command I can see that InnoDB is used by default which seems to have transactions enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is wrong, when using spring never mess around with the `current_session_context_class` unless you are using JTA. Setting it to thread disables springs proper transaction management.

Next your code is also destroying proper transaction management never catch and swallow an expection, this way transactionamangement fails as it will never see the exception and will try to commit. Either catch and rethrow or don't catch.

Finally you shouldn't be using `HibenateDaoSupport` and/or `HibernateTemplate` that should be considered deprecated as of Hibernate 3.0.1 (around 2006). Use the `SessionFactory` directly as explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight).

Basically your dao should look like this

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CsciPermSystemDAO implements ICsciPermSystemDAO {

    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Integer addPermission(Permissions Permission) throws DaoException {
        LOGGER.info("Is transaction active?:" + DebugUtils.transactionActive() );
        return (Integer) sf.getCurrentSession().save(permission);
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sf=sf;
    }
}
```

Another hint your `hibernate.connection` and `c3p0` properties in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file are useless. You are injecting a datasource and those properties are only used when hibernate manages the datasource/connection.

Regarding your spring configuration `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`. On your session-factory configuration you are setting the `org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` remove this and instead use the `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. This saves you some xml.